# Is there a way to join a BTreeSet on whitespace while consuming it to get a string without pushing each element to a string?

Tags: memory-management, data-structures, rust

Is there a way to join a `BTreeSet` on whitespace while consuming it to get a string with each element separated by whitespace, other than by iterating over each element and pushing to a string?

My set can be very large, perhaps 10GB at most, so I would like to limit memory usage.

```
type `std::collections::BTreeSet<std::vec::Vec<u8>>`
```

I am using the [bio crate](https://crates.io/crates/bio) for making reverse compliments of DNA strings, which [takes and returns a `Vec<u8>`](https://github.com/rust-bio/rust-bio/blob/master/src/alphabets/dna.rs) (or at least returns `Vec<u8>`) so to avoid having to convert back and forth at some steps I want to keep them as such.

Here is an example:

```
let dna_pieces = std::fs::read_to_string(path_dna_file).expect("Unable to read file");
let dna_pieces = dna_pieces.split(" ");

let mut dna_pieces_set = BTreeSet::new();

// first adds a small set to the tree
for dna_piece in dna_pieces {
    let dna_bytes = species_kmer.to_owned().into_bytes();
    dna_pieces_set.insert(dna_bytes);
}

// then adds a bigger other set to the same tree
let dna_pieces_big_list = std::fs::read_to_string(path_dna_file_big).expect("Unable to read file");
let dna_pieces_big_list = dna_pieces_big_list.split(" ");
for dna_piece in dna_pieces_big_list {
    let dna_bytes = dna_piece.to_owned().into_bytes();
    let dna_bytes_to_rev = dna_piece.to_owned().into_bytes();
    let reverse_complement = bio::alphabets::dna::revcomp(dna_bytes_to_rev);
    if !dna_pieces_set.contains(&reverse_complement) {
        dna_pieces_set.insert(dna_bytes);
    }
}

// format the treeset into a string output_unique_dna_pieces...

std::fs::write(path_unique_dna_pieces, output_unique_dna_pieces).expect("Unable to write file");
```

Comment: You want to it be a string, but why is the inner type of the `BTreeSet` a `Vec<u8>`, but not a `String`? What do you want it to be look like in the end? An example would be good

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "My problem is that the set can be very large, perhaps 10GB at most so I would like to limit memory usage.", so why construct it as a string ? that don't make sense, just print every element with a whitespace, don't construct it.

Comment: Aside the fact, that if you really have a 10GB data structure, you're most certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: @Stargateur I'm just worried that writing them each individually to a file would be slower than writing a whole string. But perhaps I'm wrong on that.

Comment: @hellow It is working with DNA data which can be very large, but yes it's not ideal.

Comment: Provided that you use a [`BufWriter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html), then writing them each individually will almost always be faster than writing a whole string due to the time spent in allocating the string and copying data to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. If you want to avoid allocating the entire contents of the set twice, you really have two options:

1. Switch to a `HashSet` so you can use its `drain` method. Unfortunately this method does not yet exist for `BTreeSet`.

   ```
   let mut output = Vec::new(); // use with_capacity if you know an upper bound on the size
   for x in hash_set.drain() {
       output.extend_from_slice(&x);
       output.push(b' '); // add the space
   }
   ```
2. Write directly to a file instead of creating a temporary data structure. Use a `BufWriter` for fewer IO calls.

   ```
   let buffer = File::create("filename.txt")?;
   let mut writer = BufWriter::new(buffer);
   for dna_piece in dna_pieces_set.iter() {
       writer.write(dna_piece)?;
       writer.write(b" ")?; // add the space
   }
   ```

Comment: That's excellent. However, I'm writing this to import into a python script, and I get the following errors: ```writer.write(b" ")?; // add the space
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<std::io::Error>` is not implemented for `cpython::PyErr` ```

Comment: The `?` at the end of some of the lines is for propagating errors to exit the calling function with an error. You may need to handle errors differently in your situation, or do some work to convert between error types. 

If you are happy not to handle errors, and just have them trigger a panic, then you can replace the `?`s with `.unwrap()` as a quick and dirty fix.

Comment: Ok, I got it to compile at least, which I feel in Rust goes a long way. Btw, your example is wrong in using dna_piece.as_bytes() rather than just dna_piece if the tree is type ```BTreeSet<std::vec::Vec<u8>>``` as I specified, as it is already in bytes.

Comment: @simernes ah, yeah true. I'll change that

Comment: Btw, what would happen if for some reason the program crashed while writing the buffer? It's my understanding that the actual system call to write is when the BufWriter goes out of scope, so it would all add up first in the buffer, and then write, correct?

Comment: @simernes no, the buffer has a fixed size (defaulting to 8kB) and is written to disk as soon as the buffer is full.